# ARM Assembly, finding if a character is uppercase, lowercase, or a special character

Tags: assembly, arm, ascii

I have this code, and I was pretty confident it would work. But it prints the loweroutput each time. My logic was to compare r1 (where the char is) to 'a' because it has a higher ascii value that 'A'. If it is greater or equal to 'a', we know it must be a lowercase letter. If it is less than, we compare it to 'A', and then if it is greater or equal to that, it must be uppercase. And if it is less than 'A' then we know it must be a special character. But this is not working, why?

```
printchar:
    cmp r1, #'a'
    blt T1
    ldr r0, =loweroutput
    bl printf
    b exit
T1: cmp r1, #'A'
    blt T2
    ldr r0, =upperoutput
    bl printf
    b exit
T2: ldr r0, =specialoutput
    bl printf
exit:
```

Comment: Looks sensible except for the missing `bl printf` for the `T2` case. Are you sure `r1` is loaded correctly? Use a debugger to single step the code.

Comment: I fixed the printf part. So now it works with lowercase and special characters, but still doesn't recognize uppercase

Comment: There are 6 special characters between 'Z' and 'a':  [ \ ] ^ _ `, and 5 more after 'z' (before 0x80): { | } ~ del. You might want to change the code to handle these cases. You could use a 256 byte table indexed by the character value, and each entry containing a value to indicate special, upper case, lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks sane.

As mentioned in the comments, your best friend here is a debugger.  Single-step the code, watch the value of `r1`, and observe the behaviour of the `blt` instructions.  My best guess would be that the value of `r1` is incorrect on entry.

Comment: So, turns out it was a rookie mistake. I forgot to change my output string to "the string was uppercase" when i copied it from the lowercase output. So, it was getting the correct string, just not the correct words were in the string. Thank you for the help!